# Main Wordpress site with several flexible clones

Tags: content, multi-language, clone-site

I need to develop an english/spanish site. I found the [Polylang](https://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/) plugin, which seems to do the job.

But I also need to have several spanish mirrors with similar, yet unique content and this is where I am stumped. I need to have mirror sites for Venezuela, Colombia, Argentina, etc.

The plan is for the spanish site to be the master and all of the other regional spanish sites to be clones of it, yet those clones need to be flexible enough for the content to be different and also so they don't clash with Google SEO rules.

Can anyone suggest an approach or a tutorial where something like this is mentioned?

Thanks.